# Changing directories in python using the os library

Tags: python, directory

I have been trying to make a python code to move throughout directories, but it keeps throwing error after error. Here is the code:

```
import os
def ddir(x):          # ↓ way to access a user input directory
    os.chdir(os.getcwd() )
    print("Changed to the", os.getcwd(), "directory.")
while True:
    try:
        _h = input('')
        if (_h == 'dir'):
           ddir(_h)
    #except is further down in the code
```

I have tried multiple different ways including the `shutil` library and they have not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the below codes. They are derived from the codes you wrote.

```
import os

def ddir(x):
    # First make the following line a comment.
    # os.chdir(os.getcwd())
    # Then call os.chdir() with x argument.
    os.chdir(x)
    print("Changed to the", x, "directory.")

while True:
    directory = input("Dir: ")
    try:
        #try changing the directory 
        ddir(directory)
    except OSError as err: # except "No such file or directory" error.
        print(err) # Show the error to the user.
```